# MyButton extends Button , but it already exist in layout.xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to write ButtonListener and Button init in separate file, not in MainActivity.java

Ok, I created MyButton class (extends Button), writed constructor and OnClick.Listener.

But how to I include it to MainActivity, it should be like

```
class MainActivity extends blabla
{
    private MyButton my_button;
    public OnCreate 
    {
         my_button = findViewById(id); // this obviously doesnt work
```

The problem is the button already exists, been defined in layout.xml

What is the right way to connect button in layout.xml with MyButton class, or is another way to write button init (f.e. Caption change) and implementation (OnClick) in separate source file.

Thank you, Captain Stack!

Comment: Its a custom Button? Post the xml and the Custom View

Answer (score 0):

my_button = (MyButton)findViewById(id);

The function View findViewById(int) returns an View Object,it is the superClass of calss Button.You have to cast it explicitly.

for example,cars,airplanes,trains are subclasses of The Transportation.You can say:"a car is 
a transportation.",but can not say:"a transportation is a car."

I think you can understand what I mean and sorry for my poor english.